# Dialect-agnostic "NOW" function for Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model instance with a `DATE` column that I want to update to `NOW`.

I'm using SQLite, so this works:

```
instance.update({
  dateField: sequelize.fn('DATETIME', 'NOW')
});
```

However, the `DATETIME('NOW')` function is specific to SQLite.  If I switch database engines, I'll have to go back and update references to this in the code.

Is there a database/dialect-agnostic way to update a field to `NOW` with Sequelize?

I'm assuming there is, since Sequelize knows how to update the `updatedAt` fields and what not, but I don't see it documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes, I can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` like so:

```
instance.update({
  dateField: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

updateDate: Sequelize.fn('NOW')

Not need the second param.